# Netezza SQL - Extract Month issue

Tags: netezza

How do you extract just the month from a date in netezza SQL?

The date shows as **05DEC2010**.

I've tried extract(`MONTH FROM CONTACT_DATE)` although it doesn't work. Any ideas? I dont want just to extract a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem that your contact_date field isn't actually a date field. You probably need to use:

```
extract(month from (contact_date::date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Made the above answer complete.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ('17NOV2011' :: DATE)) AS MONTH_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the date cast doesn't work you can control it with `to_date`

```
select extract(MONTH FROM to_date('05DEC2010','DDMonYYYY'))
```

Also Works

```
select date_part('Month',to_date('05DEC2010','DDMonYYYY'))
```

Also Works

```
select to_char(to_date('05DEC2010','DDMonYYYY'),'MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select month('05DEC2010')` as a simpler and more efficient way!